# How to retrieve a list of ActiveTrustedSigners from a cloudfront distribution?

Tags: boto3, amazon-cloudfront, python-2.x

I think I have trouble understanding the boto3 documentation.

I basically want to retrieve a list of `ActiveTrustedSigners` for each cloudfront distribution.

From the documentation here http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/cloudfront.html#module-boto.cloudfront.signers I am aware of the class ActiveTrustedSigners.

However how can I retrieve it from a distribution?

Here is code

```
import boto
import os

from boto.cloudfront import CloudFrontConnection

def main():
    KEY_ID = os.environ['CF_KEY_ID']
    SECRET = os.environ['CF_SECRET']

    cnn = CloudFrontConnection(KEY_ID, SECRET)
    for dist in cnn.get_all_distributions():
        print dist.ActiveTrustedSigners()  # AttributeError: 'DistributionSummary' object has no attribute 'ActiveTrustedSigners'
```

I got an 'AttributeError' here. So how I can get from `DistributionSummary` to a list of `ActiveTrustedSigners`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can get the `Distribution` object from `DistributionSummary`, and then I can interrogate `active_signers` from there.

Here is the final version

```
import os

from boto.cloudfront import CloudFrontConnection

def main():
    KEY_ID = os.environ['CF_KEY_ID']
    SECRET = os.environ['CF_SECRET']

    cnn = CloudFrontConnection(KEY_ID, SECRET)
    for dist_summary in cnn.get_all_distributions():
        dist = dist_summary.get_distribution()
        if dist.active_signers:
            for signer in dist.active_signers:
                print signer.key_pair_ids


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```